# update background color with short sleeps in between in Android application

Tags: java, android, user-interface, sleep, invalidation

I'm trying to update the background color of a few `TextView`s in my Android application. I want to set each color with a short pause in between, ie:

```
<set TextView one's background to gold>
<pause 500ms>
<set TextView two's background to gold>
<pause 500ms>
<set TextView three's background to gold>
<pause 500ms>
```

The goal is to make some sort of progressive highlighting pattern across the boxes.

The issue that I'm having is all the boxes are updating at once, after the pause. I've [read that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#drawing) if I want to force the view to draw itself I need to call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) and I've tried that, but it didn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure if either the method I'm using to sleep is causing the issues, or if I'm not forcing the draw update with the correct method. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction:

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        int id = res.getIdentifier("txt"+Integer.toString(box[i]), "id",
                                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        TextView temp = (TextView)findViewById(id);

        // Set gold with 50% opacity
        temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd700"));
        temp.getBackground().setAlpha(127);

        // Force redraw
        temp.invalidate();

        // Sleep for half a second
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note: I *want* the main thread blocked until this sequence of background changes is updated, nothing should happen until these three `TextView`s have been updated, that's why I'm calling `sleep()` from the main UI thread.

---

**EDIT**

I attempted to use a runnable while "blocking" my main thread to do the updates in the background. If this is the way it should be handled maybe someone can point out to me where I'm going wrong:

```
    boolean moveon;
    //...
    onCreate() {
        moveon = false;
    //...

    Handler myh = new Handler();
    Runnable myr = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            Resources res = getResources();
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                id = res.getIdentifier("txt"+Integer.toString(winners[i]), "id",
                        getApplicationContext().getPackageName());      
                TextView temp = (TextView)findViewById(id);
                temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd700"));
                temp.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                temp.invalidate();
            }
            moveon = true;
        }
    };
    myh.post(myr);
    while(moveon == false){}   //blocks forever here, perhaps the update to from the
                               // runable doesn't propagate?
```

Comment: "I want the main thread blocked" -- No, you want the UI disabled during the period, not blocked, which is why they're all occurring at once. A better option would be a global boolean, let's call it "enabled," and set that to false during the operation, then to true when the updates have completed, while calling postInvalidate() from the secondary thread. Then in your UI thread you should check to see if enabled is equal to true before allowing any additional operations to take place. This will create the illusion of being blocked without it actually being blocked.

Comment: @Guardanis - Is putting main UI thread into a infinite `while` loop waiting for a global to update any more efficient than telling it to sleep? "blocked", "disabled", "stalled"... whatever, it's not moving until the updates I require are done. I see that as the same thing, what I don't get is why `invalidate()` isn't causing an update to the UI. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: It actually is updating the UI, but the onDraw(Canvas) call doesn't occur immediately after calling invalidate(). The system will queue it up, which appears to be occurring after all your sleeps have finished because the UI thread is blocked by your sleeping calls. If you check the docs for invalidate you should notice the line: "will be called at some point in the future."

Comment: @Guardanis - Please see the edit, I gave a quick attempt at what I thought you were suggesting. I'm guessing I'm using the `Handler`/`Runnable` incorrectly because it never updates the global `boolean`. I take it you had something a little different in mind? Or do I actually have to do something specific to spawn a second thread to run the handler?

Comment: See my answer, tried to explain it better there with more space and code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to take the comments I made and post them here as well:

> "I want the main thread blocked" -- No, you want the UI disabled
>   during the period, not blocked, which is why they're all occurring at
>   once. A better option would be a global boolean, let's call it
>   "enabled," and set that to false during the operation, then to true
>   when the updates have completed, while calling postInvalidate() from
>   the secondary thread. Then in your UI thread you should check to see
>   if enabled is equal to true before allowing any additional operations
>   to take place. This will create the illusion of being blocked without
>   it actually being blocked

Now, taking your code:

```
boolean moveon;
//...
onCreate() {
    moveon = false;
//...

Handler myh = new Handler();
Runnable myr = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            id = res.getIdentifier("txt"+Integer.toString(winners[i]), "id",
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName());      
            TextView temp = (TextView)findViewById(id);
            temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd700"));
            temp.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
            temp.invalidate();
        }
        moveon = true;
    }
};
myh.post(myr);
while(moveon == false){}
```

You're close:

```
boolean moveon;
//...
onCreate() {
    moveon = false;
//...

// Still in UI thread here
Handler myh = new Handler();
final Resources res = getResources(); // final so we can access it inside second thread
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        // In second thread
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            // Now we use the Handler to post back to the UI thread from the second thread
            myh.post(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() {
                   // In UI thread, update here and then invalidate
                   id = res.getIdentifier("txt"+Integer.toString(winners[i]), "id",
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName());      
                   TextView temp = (TextView)findViewById(id);
                   temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd700"));
                   temp.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
                   temp.postInvalidate();
                }
            });

            Thread.sleep(delayMs); // Sleep second thread
        }
        myh.post(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() {
                   // In UI thread, reset the moveon to true on correct thread
                   moveon = true;
                }
            });
    }
}).start();
```

Then don't use your while-loop, as that will still just block the UI and give you the same problem. What you want to do instead is check if moveon == true before allowing the user to do anything else; no loop necessary.

Comment: This looks great, one point for you, that `int i` in the `for` loop needs to be made global, the local `i` can't be accessed from the inner `run()` function. Other than that this works for me. Now I need to read it through a few times to make sure I understand ***why*** it works. :)

Comment: You got me there XD But glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its really fits your exact requirement ,but you can try with ValueAnimator by setting delay to update animation color.

Here is the sample code which I tried with two textviews.

```
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    final ValueAnimator colorAnimation1 = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.YELLOW, Color.YELLOW);
    final ValueAnimator colorAnimation2 = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.YELLOW, Color.YELLOW);

    colorAnimation1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            textView1.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            colorAnimation2.setStartDelay(500);
            colorAnimation2.start();

        }

    });
    colorAnimation1.setStartDelay(500);
    colorAnimation1.start();

    colorAnimation2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            textView2.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes... that would work too, and I did consider using an animation, but it has the same problem I currently have. [`startAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)), as far as I can tell, doesn't give you anyway to wait for the animation to complete before moving on. As part of my requirements, I wanted to wait for all three of the backgrounds to finish changing color before anything else in my main thread runs.